# Should I publish a blog post about scam ideas?

Tags: social-engineering, scam

I have written and was planning on publishing a blog post about scams. The blog post talks about methods used by hackers in their Reconnaissance phase (specifically, researching individual people) and some potential social engineering methods that phone scammers could use to potentially increase their number of successful attacks.

The problem is that I'm not sure whether or not I should post the post. While my blog is small, I don't want the post to be read by a scammer and used to socially engineer others in the future.

I can give more details if they're needed, but I think I've summed up the main idea of the post, and giving too many details has pretty much the same effect as publishing the post itself.

The benefits I see to posting are:

1. Talk about an idea I had;
2. Let people know about these techniques so that they won't fall for them;
3. Drive traffic to my blog;
4. Some of these techniques are already in use by hackers, so my posting is more akin to how websites like TryHackMe talk about vulnerabilities online.

The downsides I see are:

1. Scammers could use this techniques;
2. My blog is extremely small, so most people won't see it. There's probably a higher chance of a scammer finding the post than of the post being shared around;
3. Any unethical hackers who do see the site and who didn't know this technique (few, but still a factor) would learn.

Should I post the blog post publicly, or would it better for me to keep this information to myself?

Thank you!

Comment: In general, criminals/scammers will always figure out a way to learn new techniques. If nothing else, they will set up their own forums to share tips and tricks. By posting these techniques on the internet though, you have a chance of educating honest people so that they can defend themselves from these. In short, your blog is very unlikely to have any negative impact that wouldn't have happened anyways, but may have some positive impact, so by all means, go for it.

Comment: Information can be a double-edged sword. But quite likely, any information and tips you are about to reveal already exist elsewhere in some form. And if you encounter a novel attack, raising awareness is usually justified, unless there is no current remedy and plenty of potential for abuse. Think for example about how people who report flaws in software wait until a fix has been released by the vendor to proceed with full disclosure.

Comment: Update: I ended up posting the blog post. If you're interested, [here](https://codegito.xyz/2022/05/01/telemarketing-2-0/) is a link to the post.